# Is it practical to add any of this to your answer "Hope it helps. If so, please press upvote and mark as answer :-)."

Tags: discussion

I have seen few answers that are asking for upvotes and just wondering if that's something we welcome at SE.

Comment: It could help... if there are 4 answer, some of them are cleary aceptable and the user having done his homework yet again "forgets" to mark a choice. In that case it wouldn't be for the rep (if the user is honest, that is), it is to mark the question as "done" and to help future viewer in evaluating quality. Anyway, there is a similar post on the main meta if you want to give it a look: [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160830/is-it-polite-legal-to-ask-the-question-owner-to-mark-my-answer-as-the-best)

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Ta, I do it myself sometimes but wanted to make sure if its alright.

Comment: I belive that you will always find someone that gets angry or think it is impolite. Imho, there should be no problem if the adivce is given to remember how the site should work to vampires that often forget that... but you are bound to find someone that will think the opposite and attack you. So I can only advise to use care.

Comment: Anyway, it could be usefull to see what our comunity thinks about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I think these types of comments are just noise.

I would encourage people to resist the temptation to beg for votes. And appending "hope it helps" to your answer is as much use as questioners adding "please answer my question" or "thanks in advance" and the like. It just dilutes the valuable content.

By the way, if you find this answer useful PLEASE, PLEASE, PLEASE UPVOTE IT!!!!! I am desperate for reputation.

Hope that helps, etc.

Comment: As a side note, I will write "Hope it helps" sometimes, but only when I'm not sure if my answer actually solves their issue. If my answer is more of a guideline to help them get where they need to be rather than an actual step-by-step solution (walkthrough), I tend to find myself writing that. "Please upvote", on the other hand, is always noise in my opinion.

Comment: Like the end of my answer here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59768/access-services-cant-get-it-working-and-ive-installed-everything-five-times

Comment: I take your point but I always get a little annoyed when i spend time make an honest attempt at answering or if I KNOW my answer is correct and it never get set as the answer. Also I think it an answer is being marked as correct then it should also receive 1 vote up by default...does this happen?

Comment: You get 10 for an up-vote, 15 for accepted answer. As the questioner you can up-vote an answer, accept it or do both. See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation.